# restringir opções para os campos type="date" e type="time"

Tags: html5, data, time

Estou fazendo um form de agendamento. A empresa não é 24h e nem funciona todos os dias da semana. Neste caso preciso restringir as opções de acordo com o calendário da empresa.
Pensei em validar com js, mas isso será anti funcional, uma fez que vou permitir a seleção da data e só depois informar que não é possível.
Eu precisava de algum tipo de código que exibisse somente os dias disponível. Exemplos:
`<input type="date">`:exibe datas de segunda a sexta 
`<input type="time">`:exibe horas de 8h as 18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para permitir selecionar somente as horas de 8 às 18 no campo `time`, basta utilizar os atributos `min` e `max`:

```html
Hora <input type="time" min="08:00" max="18:00">
```

Já com relação ao campo do tipo `date`, nesse [link](http://jsbin.com/rolifo/3/edit?html,output) foi feito algo desse tipo. Nativamente o HTML não oferece nenhum atributo para fazer esse tipo de limitação, então teria que ser feito com jQuery, conforme mostrado no link acima.

Comment: Cara, isso era exatamente o que eu precisava. Valeu pela ajuda!